# xCode upgrade missing simulators. How can I use locally stored simulators?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I've faces this problem a lot of times that whenever I do an upgrade to xCode. It deletes my old Simulators and I've to download them again. Can any one let any other process. That probably to copy old simulator folders and paste them to xCode contents/Developer/Platform/.....

Or is there any process to add simulators in xCode stored locally rather than downloading them again n again.

Comment: You will have to download them again, as they are made to work with this version of XCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Finder> Goto following path

> Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs

Here, you can see all your simulator SDK's.

Now, here is the trick which I follow.

- Goto the above path of your older version Xcode(say, Xcode 5.0.2) where you've
  all the  downloaded simulator SDKs.
- Copy the SDK folder(s) of required simulator.
- Now, goto the above path of upgraded version Xcode(say, Xcode 5.1) & Paste the SDKs.
- Relaunch simulator.

*Hardware>Device>iPad/iPhone* should be showing what you are looking for. Also, relaunch Xcode to update simulator list.

Comment: thanks for the ans. It worked. Do you know where does OSX places old version of xcode. it's not in trash even

Comment: @TheSaad Well, thats out of my reach! But, I don't think OS X will move it to Trash. Thats not how update works, I guess. Upgrade file download has lesser size than complete download file.

Comment: lolx. OSX is mad dude. I know upgrade has lesser size but mostly I've faced it downloads the complete file

Answer (score 5):

There's an interesting [answer on the Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4611):

> In Xcode the Window menu, select "Devices", also includes a list of
>   Simulators.  You can Add "+" ones that are not there.

That fixed things for my Xcode 7.1 beta (7B60)

Answer (score 5):

Just closing the projects, quitting Xcode and restarting Xcode worked for me